# Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' when migrating from Spring-Boot 2.2.2 t Spring-Boot 2.3.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been upgraded the spring-Boot version to 4.3.7 but I got this:
Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory'

What is the problem?

Comment: There is far too little information to answer this question. Please add additional information (the stack trace and actual error message for instance).